# API Timeout on React Native Pepperoni Starter Kit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I'm using React Native Pepperoni Starter Kit. I using one the function `post` to fetch data from the server. Whenever I make the call, API fails because of timeout but server receives the call. The only client shows it has failed.

`onboardingState.js`

```
   export function validatePhone(phoneNumber){
  return dispatch => {
    post('/api/users/register',{
      number : phoneNumber,
      deviceInfo : {}
    },false).then((res)=>{
      console.log('POST SUCCESS');
      console.log(res);
    }).catch((error)=>{
      console.log('POST ERROR');
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

File I'm using to make the call.
[api.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/futurice/pepperoni-app-kit/master/src/utils/api.js)

Comment: I think you´re missing the URL. you're using as url `'/api/users/register'`, I think you must use as url something like this `'http://ipaddress:port/api/users/register'`. What's the API URL you are trying to reach?

Comment: I have set the base URL before this. End URL is correct and the server is receiving the request.

Comment: Assuming that, I would say that you are missing the reject part on then. It should be `.then((ok_resp) => { }, (error_resp) => { /* promise has been rejected */ })`. Post must trying to reject the promise but you haven't past reject callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the reject callback.

Try this:

```js
export function validatePhone(phoneNumber){
  return dispatch => {
    post('/api/users/register',{
      number : phoneNumber,
      deviceInfo : {}
    }, false)
    .then((res)=>{
      console.log('POST SUCCESS');
      console.log(res);
    }, (cause) => {
      console.log('POST REJECTED');
      console.log(cause);
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
      console.log('POST ERROR');
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Let me know if it works. There isn't too much information, but It seems lack of reject callback is causing the failure. I mean, lack of reject callback is preventing you to realize the original error you are receiving.

You must to ensure that the server is responding correctly. An scenario could be your server receiving the request but not sending the response to the client. Did you check it?

There is default timeout into Api.js of 6 seconds and it seems not to be able to be modified. Check 8th line in Api.js, you will see this:

```
const TIMEOUT = 6000;
```

Consider using another lib in order to fetch your info from the server like [fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch) or modify by your own Api.js to set that TIMEOUT larger.

Comment: I used this code and going to `POST REJECTED` and timeout error. Server is responding correctly and sending OTP.

Comment: But what did you see on rejected callback? What did the cause say?

Comment: `cause` is timeout.

Comment: Well, it could be caused by many reasons. Did you configure any timeout time? How many seconds is taking your server? There is a default constant setting a timeout of 6 seconds in that Api.js. `const TIMEOUT = 6000;`

Comment: Why are you using Api.js? Did you try with [fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch)?

Comment: i'm using it because of 2 reasons. it came bundled with pepperoni-starter-kit and I want to attach an Auth header with every request. 

btw, I have not modified `timeout`, for me also it's 6000

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136395/discussion-between-raman-choudhary-and-facundo-la-rocca).

Comment: I think that time out is causing your problems. In order to test it I think you have two options: 
1- Download the lib a modify it changing TIMEOUT
2- Fake your post method on the server to avoid time processing.
What I recommend:
- Use [fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch) lib

Comment: i have removed timeout from function from api.js and it's working fine.